# the ngAnimate module douse not load in any of the browsers

Tags: angularjs, ng-animate

I have written a simple code which gets a list items from a php file using the get method. They are displayed successfully, but however, when injecting the ngAnimate module it seems that its not working properly:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
         <html>

        <head>
     <script src= "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
     <script src= "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.14/angular-animate.min.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">
.slide.ng-enter.ng-enter-active,
.slide.ng-leave {
    opacity: 1;
    height: 80px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.slide.ng-leave.ng-leave-active,
.slide.ng-leave {
    opacity: 0;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
</style>

</head>

<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl"> 
<input type='text' ng-model='search' placeholder="Search Here">
<ul>
  <li ng-animate="animate" class="slide" ng-repeat="x in names | filter: search">
    {{ (x.Name | uppercase)  + ', ' + x.Country }}
  </li>
</ul>

</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngAnimate']);
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get("http://www.w3schools.com/angular/customers.php")
  .success(function (response) {$scope.names = response.records;});
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have tried using the same version for both angular.js and animate.js and the problem is still existing

Comment: I see one file is loaded from `http://` and the other from `https://`. It is quite possible for one of the two to fail due to CORS issues. Did you try downloading the files and load them from your own machine?

Comment: @Loupax
Dear, I tried downloading both, the ng-animate module and the angular.js framework and they are both of the same version (1.2.19) and yet they never worked properly.

But i was trying them on a single webpage application, using MEAN

Comment: @Loupax
Loaded from 'http://'  and still not functional

[link](http://plnkr.co/edit/xvvso0rf1GlyGqiheu8O?p=preview)

Comment: I copy-pasted the HTML in the link you provided, and put it in a local HTML file. The `nganimate` files loaded properly. After that it was all about correcting CSS

Comment: @Loupax
May you please copy it back again and paste it below.
I will be thankful to know what went wrong :)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the issue;
it was a CSS typo error which I was able to debug:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

<script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.6/angular.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.6/angular-animate.js"></script>

 <style type="text/css">
  .ng-enter {
    transition:0.75s;
    opacity:0;
  }

  .ng-enter-stagger{
    transition-delay:0.3s;
  }
  .ng-enter-active {
    opacity:1;
  }

  .ng-leave-stagger{
    transition-delay:0.3s;
  }

  .ng-leave {
    transition:0.75s;
    opacity:1;
  }

  .ng-leave-active {
    opacity:0;
  }
</style>
```

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl">
 <input type='text' ng-model='search' placeholder="Search Here">
 <ul>
    <li ng-animate="'animate'" class="slide" ng-repeat="x in names | filter:   search">
     {{ (x.Name | uppercase) + ', ' + x.Country }}
    </li>
    </ul>

    </div>

  <script>
  var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngAnimate']);
   app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
     $http.get("http://www.w3schools.com/angular/customers.php")
     .success(function(response) {
       $scope.names = response.records;
      });
     });
   </script>

  </body>

  </html>
```

Comment: @loupax
there you go dear